# is this code useful?

Tags: python, encode

```
def _oauth_escape(val):
    if isinstance(val, unicode):# useful ?
        val = val.encode("utf-8")#useful ?
    return urllib.quote(val, safe="~")
```

i think it is not useful ,

yes ??

**updated**

i think unicode is ‘utf-8’  ,yes ?

Comment: Unicode is not UTF-8. They are different things, but you'll often see them discussed together. The link in ivo's answer is a good reference to start with.

Answer (score 1):

utf-8 is an encoding, a recipe for concretely representing unicode data as a series of bytes. This is one of many such encodings. Python `str` objects are bytestrings, which can represent arbitrary binary data, such as text in a specific encoding.

Python's unicode type is an abstract, not-encoded way to represent text. unicode strings can be encoded in any of many encodings.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said already, unicode and utf-8 are not the same. Utf-8 is one of many encodings for unicode.

Think of `unicode` objects as "unencoded" unicode strings, while `string` objects are encoded in a particular encoding (unfortunately, string objects don't have an attribute that tells you how they are encoded).

`val.encode("utf-8")` converts this unicode object into an utf-8 encoded string object.

In Python 2.6, this is necessary, as `urllib` can't handle unicode properly.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote(u"")
''
>>> urllib.quote(u"ä")
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py:1216: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 1216, in quote
    res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
KeyError: u'\xe4'
>>> urllib.quote(u"ä".encode("utf-8"))
'%C3%A4'
```

Python 3.x however, where all strings are unicode (the Python 3 equivalent to an encoded string is a `bytes` object), it is not necessary anymore.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote("ä")
'%C3%A4'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.0 all strings support Unicode, but with previous versions one has to explicitly encode strings to Unicode strings. Could that be it?

(utf-8 is not the only, but the most common encoding for Unicode. Read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).)

Comment: Both Python 2 and 3 have two string types, one for representing raw data (Python 2.x's `str` and Python 3.x's `bytes`) and one for representing text with a sequence of unicode codepoints (Python 2.x's `unicode` and Python 3.x's `str`).